Nav2- Using BehaviorTree.CPP nodes along with nav2 BT plugins
My application is dynamic object following and tracing the recorded goal poses to return to the intial pose when no /goal_update message is received for 5 seconds. I tried to modify the dynamic object follower BT from nav2 in vain. I thought that I could achieve this by only using the inbuilt BT plugin nodes of nav2 and may be the ones from BehaviorTree.cpp instead of creating my own behavior tree.
But I got an error when using Timeout decorator node. So, is it possible to achieve this by solely relying on the existing BT nodes or is it better to create a custom package to achieve this?
